# View latexmk output using texmaker's viewer

Tags: texmaker, latexmk

I am running the following command for latexmk,

> latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" %.tex -pvc -pdf

But I get the following error,

> "I have not found a previewer that is already running. So I will start it for 'file.pdf'"

and the pdf opens in adobe reader. What is the setup required to view the pdf in texmaker's internal viewer and would it also automatically update?

Comment: Try removing the p from pvc.

Comment: @HerbSchulz as in only -vc? It gives a bad option error and doesn't compile

Comment: Try removing the whole option.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yeah then it works. But I was hoping that I would be able to do live compilation, which I am now not able to

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your default preview like (`zathura`,`okular`...)

```bash
# launch the katexmk using this command :
$ latexmk -pdf -pvc -interaction=nonstopmode -outdir=build main.tex -f

# sample latexmkrc config
$ cat ~/.latexmkrc

$pdf_previewer = "zathura %O %S";
```

in the `~/.latexmkrc` the dollar in the variable `$pdf_previewer` is obligatory, then when you set the `pdf_previewer` *you need to install `Zathura` in your PATH in your PC.

```bash
# in archlinux:
$ pacman -Syy zathura zathura-pdf-mupdf
```